# split multi-band raster to separate rasters in ERDAS IMAGINE

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, erdas-imagine

I am currently using ERDAS IMAGINE 2013. I have a 28 Band MODIS image. Is there any way in IMAGINE I could split the 28 bands of the MODIS image into single band images?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Please ask only one question per Question.  If your last paragraph is important then research/ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the layer stack tool in the Spectral pull-down in the raster tab. [image]

Select the bands you want to use in the tool. For example, I'm selecting band 1 to separate the band from a 12 band raster.

[image]

Save the band you selected. The output should now be a band separated-out from the stacked image.